# I'm trying to perform math operation (specifically addition) with the contents of integer fields on my django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, addition

I'm trying to perform math operation (specifically addition) with the values of integer fields on my django models but i kept getting this warning even before running the program:
"Class 'IntegerField' does not define '**add**', so the '+' operator cannot be used on its instances"

this is my django model code:

```
class Applicants(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    p_course = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    o_course = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    grade1 = models.IntegerField(max_length=255)
    grade2 = models.IntegerField(max_length=255)
    grade3 = models.IntegerField(max_length=255)
    grade4 = models.IntegerField(max_length=255)
    grade5 = models.IntegerField(max_length=255)
    grade6 = models.IntegerField(max_length=255)
    total_grade = grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade4 + grade5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the input received from HTML comes as string.
I had to convert each grade in the views.py file
from `request.POST['grade1']`
to `int(request.POST['grade1'])` for each of the grades and used the self.grade1… method in models.py

Comment: I do not think you are correct on this one. Every field has the built in function `to_python()` ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python)) which converts the html to the correct python type. In your view you should work with `form.cleaned_data` which is a dictionary containing all form data but already turned to python and validated. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#field-data) in the example how to further process a valid form.

Comment: Because if you work with `form.cleaned_data` that function has already called the `clean()` method of your model. And therefore the computation of your `total_grade`already took place. At least that would be the django typical way. If you found a way that is working for you - more power to you, my man.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Applicants(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    p_course = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    o_course = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    grade1 = models.IntegerField()
    grade2 = models.IntegerField()
    grade3 = models.IntegerField()
    grade4 = models.IntegerField()
    grade5 = models.IntegerField()
    grade6 = models.IntegerField()
    
    @property
    def get_sum_of_grades(self):
    total_grade = self.grade1 + self.grade2 + self.grade3 + self.grade4 + self.grade4 + self.grade5
        return total_grade
```

Comment: This answer looks more reasonable than my answer. Go for this approach unless you really need the value for `total_grade` stored in your database (which I do not know why you should).

Comment: i changed it but its still not working

Comment: show me some context

Comment: this is the result i get for trying that method: Class 'IntegerField' does not define '__add__', so the '+' operator cannot be used on its instances.                                                                                            i want to display the total grades on a template

Comment: this is the template i want to display the total score on:                   <body>
<h1>List Of Applicants</h1>
<ol>
    {% for x in myapplicants %}
        <li>{{ x.fname }} {{ x.lname }} {{ x.p_course }} {{ x.total_grade }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
</body>

Comment: {{ x.get_sum_of_grades}} <- here call property name.

if not work, add field total_grades = models.IntegerField() , then overwrite save:
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_grades = self.grade1 + self.grade2 + self.grade3 + self.grade4 + self.grade4 + self.grade5
        return super(Applicants, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Answer (score 2):

> Model.clean()¶
>
> This method should be used to provide custom model validation, and to
> modify attributes on your model if desired. For instance, you could
> use it to automatically provide a value for a field, or to do
> validation that requires access to more than a single field ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean))

As described here, you should implement a clean method to your model:

```py
class Applicants(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    p_course = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    o_course = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    grade1 = models.IntegerField()
    grade2 = models.IntegerField()
    grade3 = models.IntegerField()  # btw Integerfields don't have `max_lenght`
    grade4 = models.IntegerField()
    grade5 = models.IntegerField()
    grade6 = models.IntegerField()
    total_grade = models.IntegerField()

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        self.total_grade = sum([self.grade1, self.grade2, self.grade3, self.grade4, self.grade4, self.grade5])
```

For sure that `total_grade` field will be shown in a form if you choose to use a `models.ModelForm` but you can go for `exclude = ['total_grade']` to hide it. Be careful, the result of the computation does not reach "normal" form validation, as it runs before within the statement `super().clean()`

Comment: this is the new error: Unexpected argument(s)Possible callees:sum(__iterable: Iterable[_T], __start: _S)sum(__iterable: Iterable[_T])sum(__iterable: Iterable[_T], start: _S)sum(__iterable: Iterable[_T])

Comment: Yeah, ok my bad. The `sum` function takes a list as parameter. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: I tried both methods and still the result is the same

Comment: Then delete the `sum` function and go for your inital approach with the plus operator again: `self.total_grade = self.grade1 +  self.grade2 + ... `

Comment: Thank you very much sir, it turns out that the main problem is from my views file, I had to convert the inputs to integers